# Node.js Socket on Disconnect Update User List on Server Side

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a chat room that have an active user list.

On new connection, the username is emitted to the server, the server adds it to the array and send the username back to all connected sockets to add that new username to the user list. It works fine.

However, I can't seem to do the removing of user from the array.
On the client side, I want to emit event to the server to let it know which user is leaving and update accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to emit any event from client-side to tell the server the client is disconnect.

Just listen to the `disconnect` event on server-side :

https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#event-disconnect

```
socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
  // remove user from the array
  // broadcast the updated user list to connected sockets
});
```